# localStorage getItem() Method is not retrieving data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the Items from Browser Local Storage, but unable, please help me out.
But I can't retrieve the stored data from localStorage. My Web Developer Tools show me that stored Data exists, but when I turn or reload the page, i won't get the data.

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";

const App = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    console.log(contact);
    setContacts([...contacts, contact]);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    const retrieveContacts = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
    );
    if (retrieveContacts) {
      setContacts(retrieveContacts);
    }
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="app">

        <Header />
        <AddContact addContactHandler={addContactHandler} />
        <ContactList contacts={contacts} />

      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I checked out the references. But still it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All useEffects are run for one time at the time of rendering. So initially your contacts state is `[]` and you are storing it into localStorage.

So to solve it, try adding simple if check while storing into localStorage.

See comment in code for more explanation.

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";

const App = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    console.log(contact);
    setContacts([...contacts, contact]);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    const retrieveContacts = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
    );
    if (retrieveContacts) {
      setContacts(retrieveContacts);
    }
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    if(contacts.length) { // Only store if contacts is not empty
       localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
    }
  }, [contacts]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="app">

        <Header />
        <AddContact addContactHandler={addContactHandler} />
        <ContactList contacts={contacts} />

      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Like stated before

```
 useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
 }, [contacts]);
```

When the component mounts, this effect is called and since state at time point always is an empty array ([]) as stated in the default value of useState this will set the local storage to empty array ([]).

This happens when the app is running in `<StrictMode>` which is a good thing.
When in StrictMode, react is running the useEffects twice, to be sure that there is no unsafe lifecycles.

so both render and "shouldComponentUpdate" methods are running twice. hence the problem.

Be sure to not disable Strict mode but fix the lifecycle instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Why doesn't it work?

Your first `useEffect` is working fine

```
useEffect(() => {
  const retrieveContacts = JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
  );
  if (retrieveContacts) {
    setContacts(retrieveContacts);
  }
}, []);
```

But this `setContacts(retrieveContacts)` doesn't change the state before the second `useEffect` runs so `contacts` below is `[]`

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
}, [contacts]);
```

### How to make it work?

You could check if `contacts` is not empty, but it will cause bugs when removing items

You can either update the store every time you change contacts:

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";

const App = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    const newContacts = [...contacts, contact];
    setContacts(newContacts);
    updateStorage(newContacts);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const retrieveContacts = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
    );
    if (retrieveContacts) {
      setContacts(retrieveContacts);
    }
  }, []);

  const updateStorage = (items) => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(items));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <AddContact addContactHandler={addContactHandler} />
        <ContactList contacts={contacts} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Or load the store in the state initializer:

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";

const App = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(() => {
    const retrieveContacts = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
    );
    if (retrieveContacts) {
      return retrieveContacts;
    }

    return [];
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);

  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    const newContacts = [...contacts, contact];
    setContacts(newContacts);
    updateStorage(newContacts);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <AddContact addContactHandler={addContactHandler} />
        <ContactList contacts={contacts} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Or combine both approaches